# What word should be used to describe a sports event?

Tags: word-choice

As in "enjoy your sports event".

I've considered using just event, but I think it's too generic. 
I've also considered "race" but not every sports event is a race. 
Maybe there isn't a proper word for this in English.

Comment: I don't think you'll get a better description for a sporting event than... sporting event.

Comment: Oh that was a mistake that came from the editing, it was "an event" at first, my bad!

Comment: The thing is, this is for an online platform that works only with sporting events, so saying sporting event is redundant. Should I just say event?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of terms for sporting events. Unfortunately each can have its own particular term:

The most generic is "game":

> Enjoy the **game**!

This is appropriate for sports like baseball, football/soccer, basketball, and so on.

Tennis, however plays a **match**, as does boxing and other **one-on-one** sports/games.

A single boxing (or other fighting sport) match can also be called a **bout**.

Golfers play a **round** of golf, but a complete set of rounds, often over a period of days is called a **tournament**.

Other sports can also have tournaments, especially when each contestant plays against more than one opponent.  For example, a table tennis tournament will consist of a series of *matches*, with players being eliminated until you get to the **final match** to determine the tournament winner.

**Race** is appropriate for sports that are contests of speed -- biking, running, horse racing, auto racing, etc.

A collective event which might have many different types of sports all going on at the same time can be called a **meet**.  Sports such as "track and field" or swimming have *meets* against their opponents, where all the different events go on at the same time, in different areas.

Some sports have their own unique terminology.  Cricket, for example, calls their games a **Test match** or simply a **Test** (although there are variations with other names).

This is not meant to be a complete list, but it should be enough to get started.

Comment: This is very helpful. I was actually thinking about using **test**, but that feels  like I'm telling them to enjoy their math exam.. I think I will stick to **event** but thank you kindly for your excellent response! 
Edit: this is supposed to be an automatic response so I can't really change it depending on the situation. It has to be valid for all possible cases. (we use **prueba** in spanish)

Comment: @Cilvet  "test" only applies to cricket, and then only certain variations of cricket.  I think "game" is generally acceptable.

Comment: wouldn't **game** be unfitting in the context of, say, a race?

Comment: Good answer, Andrew. @Cilvet yes, "game" would be unfitting for racing sports and sports covered within *meets* (many of which are races anyway), but it is a good generic choice for just about everything else. Even sports like golf or tennis that have their own specific terminology can be described as "games."

Comment: How about *competition?*

Comment: @Davo sure, although that sounds like something you would say to someone *competing* in the competition, along with "Good luck!" or some similar show of support.

Comment: I suppose. I enjoy the competition presented in American Ninja Warrior, although I don't compete myself. Any event where score is kept is a competition, from racing to darts to weightlifting to debate to the math team.